# Why photons have not magnetic moment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, photons, quantum-spin, elementary-particles

Spin of a particle is a magnetic moment.
Photon have spin-1, so why photon have not a magnetic moment because only 0-spin particles can not have a magnetic moment?

Comment: *"Spin of a particle is a magnetic moment"* Why do you think so? Just because particles with spin *have* a magnetic moment, that doesn't mean spin *is* that magnetic moment.

Comment: Welcome Khan. You might want to look at the closely related question [Unlike electrons, photons don't have a magnetic moment despite having a spin. Why?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/640117/145491).

Comment: Do photons couple to photons?

Comment: @Cosma-Zachos Yes, higher order [two-photon processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics) do couple photons very weakly to photons. I believe the photon anomalous  magnetic moment induced in hyperintense magnetic fields is due to triangular $\gamma\rightarrow \gamma\gamma$ photon splitting processes that are impossible for free photons, but can happen in the magnetic fields such as those around [neutron stars](https://ir.lib.uwo.ca/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1122&context=physicspub).

Comment: @David Baily. Of course, but do you seriously believe the OP is asking about induced loop couplings?  There is no triangular effective coupling for vector couplings.

Comment: @Cosma-Zachos No, I don't think the OP is asking about induced loop couplings, but you asked and I wasn't sure if it was rhetorically directed at the OP or an actual question. You are certainly correct that I should have left out the word "triangular". My mental image of photon-splitting ignored the 4th virtual photon from the magnetic field.

Comment: I think you will have a better understanding of the spin if you understand why spin is assigned to particles at the quantum level. It was **necessary** to do that so that the law of angular momentum conservation should hold as a law at the quantum level,  Maybe my answer here helps https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/540328/angular-momentum-of-a-single-particle/540529#540529